# convert point form decimal to octal in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int deci, rem,  octal=0,  i=1;
    float de,  x,y,point,rem1;

    cout<<"enter the decimal"<<endl;
    cin>>deci;
    deci=y;
    de=y-deci;

    while(deci!=0)
    {
        rem= deci  %  8;
        deci=deci  /  8;
        octal+=rem*i;
        i=i*10;
    }
    while (de!=0)
    {
        point=de  *  8;
    }

    cout<<"the octal is "<<octal<<"."<<point<<endl;
}
```

when i enter 12.5 it should give me 14.4 but instead of it displays 14.0 but according to the logic it should consider y as a 12.5 and deci as a 12 according to int and float but it consider both as 12.5 ...

Comment: Hint: add `cout << deci << endl;` right after `cin >> deci` and see what happens to `.5`

Comment: look at the value of deci with your debugger

Comment: You're "converting" your number to a different number, not to the same number in octal. Decimal and octal are textual representations.

Comment: `cin >> deci; deci = y;` The first statement reads a value into `deci`; the next one copies the (uninitialized) value of `y` into `deci`, replacing whatever was just read in.

Comment: There is no way it "considers" `deci` to be 12.5. That is impossible.

Comment: @molbdnilo To be fair, with some arithmetic hackery, you can "fake it" such that the decimal representation of your new number is the same as the octal representation of the old one, which saves you modifying your representation algorithm (i.e. IOStream's default output). Forgetting for a minute that this is a silly approach (`std::oct`!) the conclusion is that this isn't _necessarily_ a "wrong" thing to do, although it may in some cases (IMO not this case) be a red flag that someone's forgotten _a number is a number is a number_!

Comment: `cin>>deci; deci=y;` This makes no sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 12.5 decimal is not 14.5 octal. Wouldn't it be 14.4 (8 + 4 + 4/8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int deci, rem,  octal=0,  i=1;

 float de,  x,y,point,rem1;

  cout<<"enter the decimal"<<endl;
  cin>>deci;
```

Since `deci` is declared as `int` `cin>>deci` and entering '12.5' will set `deci` to 12

BTW I assume the next line is a transcription typo `deci=y` doesnt make any sense at all. I assume you mean `y = deci`

Solution - declare deci as a float;

Comment: thanks sir this method helped me and worked perfectly